# How to properly translate shadow DOM CSS selectors to non-shadow-DOM selectors

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, polymer, shadow-dom

I want to test Polymer applications with non-Shadow-DOM capable browsers like Firefox, PhantomJS, and maybe others using WebDriver.
WebDriver commands for Firefox and PhantomJS fail when I use something like

```
driver.findElement(const By.cssSelector('* /deep/ #some-div'));
```

Are there some rules how to best translated/approximate these selectors when the polyfills can not be applied:

- `/deep/`
- `::shadow`
- `:host()`
- `:host-context()`
- `:content`

I would like to create a function that translates such selectors automatically to non-shadow-DOM selectors for browsers that don't support them before sending the request and for that I need to know how to translate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question is a bit old, but in case you haven't figured it out yourselves yet.

- **/deep/** (deprecated): As you said in your answer, just removing it should work in most of the cases.
- **::shadow** (deprecated): Can also just be removed. Replacing it with > might not work if node which you are targeting is not an immediate child of host element's shadow root.
- **:host()** pseudo classes is used to select custom element from **inside** shadow-dom, in non-supported browsers it will be equal to selecting parent from child element. Since we [don't have parent selectors](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/) in css and you are writing js for conversion, you can identify tagName of host element and use it instead of :host selector. Something like below:

```css
:host {
  opacity: 0.4;
  transition: opacity 420ms ease-in-out;
}
:host(:hover) {
  opacity: 1;
}
:host(:active) {
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
}
/*Convert it to*/

x-element {
  opacity: 0.4;
  transition: opacity 420ms ease-in-out;
}
x-element:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
x-element:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
}
```

- **:host-context(`<selector>`)** pseudo class matches the host element if it or any of its ancestors matches `<selector>`. for example: 
  Below rule will apply on custom element only when it's a descendant of an element with the class `.different`.

```css
:host-context(.different) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<body class="different">
  <x-foo></x-foo>
</body>
```

It won't be very easy to replace this one with anything simple. Even [webcomponents polyfill](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs) doesn't attempt it. I can't think of any css only way to achieve this.

- **::content** targets distributed child nodes of host element, i.e. all elements which are *picked* to display using content selectors. Replacing ::content selectors with tagName of host elements should work here. i.e.

```css
::content > h3 {
  color: green;
}

/*replace it with*/

x-element h3 {
  color: green;
}
```

Note that I have removed child selector `>` also from above, because in non-supported browsers after distribution h3 won't be a direct descendant of x-element anymore. Given the way content selector is used, I'd suggest removing child selector also wherever available.

Answer (score 1):

- `/deep/` can just be removed
- `::shadow` can be replaced by `>`

don't know about the others yet

Comment: Trying to just remove `/deep/` and `::shadow` works in Chrome and Firefox but things blow up on me in Safari (and I think IE).  Were you able to get this working consistently?

Comment: I wonder why this works for you in Chrome, it should only work in browsers without shadow DOM support. I experienced this problem in IE/Edge too (didn't try  Safari yet). My workaround is recursively calling `shadowRoot.querySelectorAll()` instead of `/deep/` and `::shadow`. To me it looks like the reason is that IE (and probably also Safaru) have enabled shadow DOM (but not officially confirmed) but don't support `/deep/` and `::shadow` yet in `querySelector`.

Comment: I misspoke, I just disabled replacing `/deep/` when running in Chrome ... so the scheme works in Chrome and Firefox.  However, this comment thread is out-of-scope for SO, see [webdriver.io](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/194) and [selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1041) issues.